# Convert all variables into ordered factors

Tags: r

I am using the semTools package to carry out EFA using categorical data. The efaUnrotate() function requires variables as ordered factors.

I am trying to convert all of my already factor variables into an ordered one using a simple code, which does not seem to work unfortunately. I wonder if anyone had an explanation for this?

My data:

```
test <- structure(list(fp_weightloss = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), fp_gripstrength = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
    fp_walktime = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), fp_metmins = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

My code:

```
test_ord <- as.data.frame(sapply(test, as.ordered))

sapply(test_ord, class)
```

Results in no change:

```
  fp_weightloss fp_gripstrength     fp_walktime      fp_metmins 
       "factor"        "factor"        "factor"        "factor"
```

When I would expect:

```
class(as.ordered(test$fp_weightloss))
[1] "ordered" "factor"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `sapply`: best avoid it entirely, since its implicit conversions often invisibly mess with data, and they do here. Use `lapply` instead:

```
test_ord <- as.data.frame(lapply(test, as.ordered))
```

In general I prefer using `vapply` since it handles non-`list` return values, but getting `vapply` to work with S3 classes doesn’t seem possible.

Comment: I didn't realise that sapply messes with data (!). Thank you I'll keep that in mind in the future.